# Dynamic linq on Dynamic properties

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic

Can anyone help me with this:

I have collection of poco object with dynamic(ExpandoObject) property which need to be part of string condition in dynamic linq

ex.

```
public class Test
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   dynamic DynamicProperty {get;set;}
}
```

Dynamic property (`ExpandoObject`) has a properties(`Id` and `Name`)

how can i filter collection of Test objects using dynamic Linq, (how  should look like string where condition?):

```
IList<Test> testList;

testList.AsQueryable()
        .Where("DynamicProperty.Id == 2 or DynamicProperty.Name == "test"")
```

Comment: Convert the ExpandoObject to dictionary in you linq and then chain another filter on the dict.

Answer (score 0):

[Dynamic LINQ](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) provides a small reusable library that supports string predicates (and query language) to build dynamic LINQ statements.

[Download Link](http://www.scottgu.com/blogposts/dynquery/dynamiclinqcsharp.zip)

Comment: The Dynamic Linq library doesn't work in the example above where the property itself is declared as dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

Chain the Wheres on the same IQueryable to build a complete expression tree that can then be realised with a ToList:

```
IList<string> testList = new List<string>() {"One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five"};

var filteredList = testList.AsQueryable().Where((s) => s.Length <= 4);
filteredList = filteredList.Where((s) => s[0].Equals('F'));

var results = filteredList.ToList();
```

Comment: thanax guys, but my where condition must be a string which is going to be used in dynamic where clause, like in example that i posted

Answer (score 0):

thanx guys, but my where condition must be a string which is going to be used in dynamic where clause, like in example that i posted. Complex property (DynamicProperty) is unknown type and must be used in filter like in example. I used ExpandoObject but have a problem with above syntax `(.Where("DynamicProperty.Id == 2 or DynamicProperty.Name == "test""))`. Because of that string structure must be like this  `.Where("DynamicProperty["Id"] == 2 or DynamicProperty["Name"] == "test""))` and because Expando has `IDictionary<string, object>` structure  all values must be explicit convert and final filter is: `.Where(Convert.ToInt32("DynamicProperty["Id"]) == 2 or DynamicProperty["Name"].ToString() == "test""))` which is a more complicated then a first one.

How to solve problem to have string filter like above example

```
"DynamicProperty.Id == 2 or DynamicProperty.Name == "test""
```